# Calculate a sum field based on two columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've have an access query that I am trying to run and can't seem to get it right.

I'm already calculating a sum of hours grouped by the name and a description column.  I would like the total column basically to give a sum of the hours by the name and the description column

```
SELECT dbo_t_SAP_AttCodes.Description, Sum(dbo_v_MES_TcActivities.Hours) AS SumOfHours, 
    Left([supervisor1email],InStr([supervisor1email],".")-1) AS [Supervisor First Name], 
    Mid([supervisor1email],InStr([supervisor1email],".")+1,
    InStr([supervisor1email],"@")-InStr([supervisor1email],".")-1) 
    AS [Supervisor Last Name], (SELECT sum([hours]) FROM [dbo_v_MES_TcActivities]     
    WHERE [costctr]="106330" AND [clockin] Between DateAdd("d",-((Weekday(Date())-1)),
    Date()) And Date()) AS Total_Hours

FROM dbo_v_MES_TcActivities LEFT JOIN dbo_t_SAP_AttCodes 
    ON dbo_v_MES_TcActivities.AttCode = dbo_t_SAP_AttCodes.Code

WHERE (((dbo_v_MES_TcActivities.AttCode) Not Like "MEAL") 
    AND ((dbo_v_MES_TcActivities.CostCtr) Like "106330") 
    AND ((dbo_v_MES_TcActivities.ClockIn) Between DateAdd("d",-((Weekday(Date())-1)),
    Date()) And Date()))

GROUP BY dbo_t_SAP_AttCodes.Description, Left([supervisor1email],
    InStr([supervisor1email],".")-1), 
    Mid([supervisor1email],InStr([supervisor1email],".")+1,
    InStr([supervisor1email],"@")-InStr([supervisor1email],".")-1), 
    dbo_v_MES_TcActivities.Supervisor1Email

ORDER BY Mid([supervisor1email],InStr([supervisor1email],".")+1,
    InStr([supervisor1email],"@")-InStr([supervisor1email],".")-1);
```

EDIT:
Here is what the current output looks like:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Quq1h.png)

Here is what I would like to see:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9avOc.png)

Comment: The only difference between *SumHours* and your desired *TotalHours* is the `(dbo_v_MES_TcActivities. AttCode) Not Like "MEAL")` condition as both will sum by *Description* and *Name*.

Comment: I added some pictures that might help clear up what I am looking for. If possible I don't want to have to worry about the meal and just pull from the existing filtered data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider turning your subquery to a correlated subquery where you match the nested `SELECT` statement to corresponding row's name in main query without *Description* (only *Name*) grouping. The below comes out long due to Supervisor first and last name calculated expressions.

Please note: below uses table aliases with *sub* and *main* (adjust all field references accordingly):

**Subquery**

```
SELECT --...same fields/expressions as original w/ 'main' alias...,
      (SELECT SUM(sub.[hours]) FROM [dbo_v_MES_TcActivities] sub    
       WHERE sub.[costctr]="106330" 
         AND sub.AttCode Not Like "MEAL"
         AND sub.[clockin] Between DateAdd("d",-((Weekday(Date())-1)), Date()) And Date()
         AND Left(sub.[supervisor1email], InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")-1) = 
             Left(main.[supervisor1email], InStr(main.[supervisor1email],".")-1) 

         AND Mid(sub.[supervisor1email], InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")+1,
                 InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],"@") - InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")-1) =
             Mid(main.[supervisor1email], InStr(main.[supervisor1email],".")+1, 
                 InStr(main.[supervisor1email],"@") - InStr(main.[supervisor1email],".")-1)
       ) AS Total_Hours
FROM dbo_v_MES_TcActivities main
LEFT JOIN dbo_t_SAP_AttCodes sap
      ON main.AttCode = sap.Code
--...same WHERE and GROUPBY as original w/ 'main' and 'sap' aliases...
```

**Derived Tables**

Alternatively, turn both aggregate queries into derived tables joined into main query. In MS Access you can even save both nested `SELECT` statements as separate, saved queries and reference them in `FROM` and `JOIN` clause. Again, note the table aliases:

```
SELECT t1.Description, t1.SumOfHours, t1.[Supervisor First Name], t1.[Supervisor Last Name], 
       t2.TotalHours    
FROM (
      SELECT --...same fields/expressions as original...
      FROM dbo_v_MES_TcActivities main
      LEFT JOIN dbo_t_SAP_AttCodes sap
           ON main.AttCode = sap.Code
      --...same WHERE and GROUPBY as original...
      ) As t1
INNER JOIN
      (
       SELECT SUM(sub.[hours]),
              Left(sub.[supervisor1email], InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")-1) 
                    AS [Supervisor First Name],
              Mid(sub.[supervisor1email], InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")+1,
                 InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],"@") - InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")-1) 
                    AS [Supervisor Last Name]
       FROM [dbo_v_MES_TcActivities] sub    
       WHERE sub.[costctr]="106330" 
         AND sub.AttCode Not Like "MEAL"
         AND sub.[clockin] Between DateAdd("d",-((Weekday(Date())-1)), Date()) And Date()
       GROUP BY
              Left(sub.[supervisor1email], InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")-1),
              Mid(sub.[supervisor1email], InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")+1,
                  InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],"@") - InStr(sub.[supervisor1email],".")-1)
       ) AS t2
ON t1.[Supervisor First Name] = t2.[Supervisor First Name]
AND t1.[Supervisor Last Name] = t2.[Supervisor Last Name]
```

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but what do you mean about the "main", "sub", and sap" aliases?

Comment: Table aliases are just temp names used to cut down long table name references for shorter queries and especially if re-using same table as in subqueries.

Comment: So `main` in `FROM dbo_v_MES_TcActivities main`is used as *temp name* for original table. I was just letting you know to keep consistency as you must uses alias if defined.